# Prototype Declaration Error when Implementing a remove function for a Queue

Tags: c, compiler-errors, queue

I am trying to implement a queue in C, and I get a prototype declaration in my `remove(q)` method.  I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong here, I am using an older version of queue implementation as an exercise, but cannot put this together.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXQUEUE 100
#define TRUE  (1==1)
#define FALSE (1==0)

struct queue {
    int items[MAXQUEUE];
    int front, rear;
};

empty(pq)
struct queue *pq;
{
    return ((pq->front == pq->rear) ? TRUE : FALSE);
}

remove(pq)
struct queue *pq;
{
    if (empty(pq)) {
        printf("queue underflow\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (pq->front == MAXQUEUE - 1)
        pq->front = 0;
    else
        (pq->front)++;
    return (pq->items[pq->front]);  
}

int main() {
    struct queue q;

    q.front = q.rear = MAXQUEUE - 1;

    if (empty(q)) {
        printf("hello");
    } else
        printf("\n sod off\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think your syntax for declaring functions might be wrong. it should be `return_type function_name(arg_type argname, ) { function_body }`. so something like `struct queue * empty(struct queue * pq) { ... }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your functions aren't functions. You need to adjust them to take a queue as an arguments and return your values like so:

```
int empty(struct queue *pq)
{
    return ((pq->front == pq ->rear) ? TRUE : FALSE);
}

int remove(struct queue *pq)
{
    if(empty(pq)){
        printf("queue underflow\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if(pq->front == MAXQUEUE-1)
        pq->front = 0;
    else
        (pq->front)++;
    return (pq->items[pq->front]);  
}
```

Making these changes along with one change in your main (`if (empty(q)` -> `if (empty(&q)`) compiles and outputs `hello`.

Comment: The OP is copying from some very old source code. This syntax used to be valid K&R syntax but has been deprecated in C99.

Answer (score 2):

what if you declare your functions like this:

```
void
empty(struct queue *pq)
{
    ...
}
```

and

```
void
remove(struct queue *pq)
{
    ...
}
```